# Spring-Boot application with Office365

Tags: spring-boot, outlook-api

I am developing a Spring-Boot application that will create users getting their data from their profile in Office365 then will syncronizate data periodically.
From Outlook Api request i can get some data as givenName,  surname, displayName but not all data for created users. How can get specific information as birthday, middleName, nickName or companyName?
How can make syncronization of users data periodically? 
Please help me with an advice or a simple example ...

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. For getting data from outlookApi i used @GET("/v1.0/me")
 Call<OutlookUser> getCurrentUser(); but this call get only some data as givenName, surname or displayName in response but no birthday or companyName etc. I made a selection as  /v1.0/me?select=Birthday but again the same response. I want to get specific data not default data that OutlookApi turned in response.

Comment: For syncronization i want a suggestion because i tried in my way but 
I didnt get good results.